# How do I ensure my dataset does not accumulate a lot of small files when running in incremental mode?

Tags: python, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

If I have a transform that runs frequently in incremental mode I accumulate at least one file per transaction.

The result is a dataset that has:

- A lot metadata stored from build logs.
- Small dataset files.

I have been told that small dataset files lead to increased build time and compute cost. I also have no need to accumulate all the build logs.

How do I ensure my dataset does not accumulate a lot of small files when running in incremental mode?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build in logic that will prevent this from happening.

By inspecting the number of output files, we can determine the incremental write mode. This enables us to read in the previous transaction's output as dataframe, and coalesce the data together, making all the small files one larger file.

We can do this by inspecting the number of files in the output dataset's file system, and using an if statement to set the `write_mode`

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output, configure, incremental
from pyspark.sql import types as T


FILE_COUNT_LIMIT = 100


# Be sure to insert your desired output schema here
# Which can be copied to the clipboard in the dataset-app
schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('Value', T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField('Time', T.TimestampType()),
    T.StructField('DataGroup', T.StringType())
])


def compute_logic(df):
    """
    This is your transforms logic
    """
    return df.filter(True)


@configure(profile=["KUBERNETES_NO_EXECUTORS"]) # or DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION_MAX_128
@incremental(semantic_version=1)
@transform(
    output=Output("/Org/Project/Folder1/Output_dataset_incremental"),
    input_df=Input("/Org/Project/Folder1/Input_dataset_incremental"),
)
def compute(input_df, output):
    df = input_df.dataframe('added')
    df = compute_logic(df)

    # Fetches a list of the files that are in the dataset
    files = list(output.filesystem(mode='previous').ls())

    if (len(files) > FILE_COUNT_LIMIT):
        # incremental merge and replace
        previous_df = output.dataframe('previous', schema)
        df = df.unionByName(previous_df)
        mode = 'replace'
        coalesce_count = 128

    else:
        # Standard incremental mode
        mode = 'modify'
        coalesce_count = 1

    output.set_mode(mode)
    output.write_dataframe(df.coalesce(coalesce_count))
```

Comment: Maybe I have missed something, but shouldn't it be df in the last two lines instead of output_df?

Comment: @RobertKossendey it was indeed incorrect, it should be the `transforms.api.IncrementalTransformOutput` instance `output`. I have corrected the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Still, you don't do anything with the data frame that is being created in this line df = df.unionByName(previous_df). Maybe I know to little about the Foundry Transform API, but coming from vanilla Spark, this looks off.

Comment: In the last line, the dataframe `df` is sent as an argument to the TransformOutput method `write_dataframe`. This causes the computation, and in the event of a successful result, the materialisation of the dataframe into parquet files and a commit of the transaction.

Comment: Missed that! Thank you :)